# Postman Submitting Raw Post Data for PHP

Tags: php, post, postman, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I tried to send a post request to a PHP script with raw data. But with the given options, as in

1. content types: (text, javascript, json, html, xml)
2. raw data

It turned out to be not possible. Because plain text or html never sets the **`$_POST`** variable on the server side.

I could not use the given `x-www-form-urlencoded` option either as that requires me to set all my raw ampersand `&` encoded post data to be set in the key value style, I did not want that, my need (**PayPal IPN Validation Callback Testing locally**) was to send all this bunch of text altogether.

[image]

So in the answer you will see what I did:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is explained pretty spot on on the screenshot but I will describe for the good of web here:

1. In Body Tab: Select raw for data
2. In Body Tab: Select Text for content type
3. In Headers Tab: Unselect `Content-Type` as this cannot be edited (automatically added).
4. In Headers Tab: Add a Key `Content-Type` for a value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image]